# angular 7 application - API call downloads a pdf but raw HTML markup is showing

Tags: html, angular, pdf, angular7

In my angular 7 application I have an API, when called, will download a PDF.  The PDF contains raw HTML tags in it.  I am trying to find a way to make the PDF file not show raw HTML in it.

Here is my methods for getting the PDF:

```
  getPdf() {
    const payload = { applicantId: this.idHeader, codes: 
    this.codeHeader + ':0', genderType: this.gender, data: this.data }

this.service.getPdfConfirmationView(payload).subscribe((pdfResponse: any) => {
  let dataType = 'application/pdf';
  let binaryData = [];
  binaryData.push(pdfResponse);
  let downloadLink = document.createElement('a');
  downloadLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob(binaryData, { type: dataType }));
  if (pdfResponse)
    downloadLink.setAttribute('download', 'ConfirmationReport');
  document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
  downloadLink.click();
  })
}
```

Here is my service for connecting to the API

```
getPdfConfirmationView(payload) {
  return this.http.get(environment.apiUrl + 
  '/v1/report/getPdfConfirmationView',
  { headers: this.getSearchApiHeaders(payload), responseType: 'blob' });
}
```

The pdf response contains markup like this:

```
pm at 1-888-123-4567 or by email at <a
href="mailto:somesupportaddress@gmail.com"
style="font-size:inherit;font-weight:bold;">somesupportaddress@gmail.com</a>.<br/
> If your mailing address or email address changes, you must make the
correction on your Application. </br><a
href="https://www.mywebsite.com/how-apply "
style="font-size:inherit;font-weight:bold;">Click here</a> for more 
information
regarding application process.
```

It PDF file should have the HTML markup applied and not shown as raw text like this.

Comment: On the HTTP request header try adding `Accept: application/json`.

Comment: https://github.com/cipchk/ngx-filesaver could help you out